# Need to apply confusionMatrix from caret to an already computed confusion matrix

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I have a confusion matrix computed with another software that is saved in a text file. There are 4 classes that do not appear in this file. We can refer the classes C1, C2, C3, C4. The content of the input file *conf_mat.txt* looks like below:

```
830 0 10 0

0 1262 18 0

3 37 1262 18

1 0 5 1314
```

I read the file as below:

```
cm <- read.table("conf_mat.txt")
```

It looks as below:

```
   V1   V2   V3   V4
1 830    0   10    0
2   0 1262   18    0
3   3   37 1262   18
4   1    0    5 1314
```

I need to compute statistics using *byClass* from these like sensitivity, specificity, F1 etc from this matrix, so *confusionMatrix* would be really useful. But I do not have the *actual* and the *predicted* lists for each sample in turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this might help someone later, this is the answer I found.

I constructed the classes according to the column of the input confusion matrix:

```
class0 <- rep(c('C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'), cm[,1])
class1 <- rep(c('C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'), cm[,2])
class2 <- rep(c('C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'), cm[,3])
class3 <- rep(c('C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'), cm[,4])
```

I made an array with the correct classes:

```
trueClass <- c(rep('C0', sum(cm[,1])), rep('C1', sum(cm[,2])), rep('C2', sum(cm[,3])), rep('C3', sum(cm[,4])))
```

And one with the predicted ones:

```
predictedClass <- c(class0, class1, class2, class3)
```

Then the confusionMatrix is applied to the two arrays

```
newCM <- confusionMatrix(predictedClass, trueClass)
newCM
```

This leads to the same confusion matrix that was read from the text file, but with additional statistics computed.

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics
              Reference
    Prediction   C0   C1   C2   C3
            C0  830    0   10    0
            C1    0 1262   18    0
            C2    3   37 1262   18
            C3    1    0    5 1314

    Overall Statistics

                   Accuracy : 0.9807          
                     95% CI : (0.9763, 0.9844)
        No Information Rate : 0.2798          
        P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16       

                      Kappa : 0.974           
     Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA              

    Statistics by Class:

                         Class: C0 Class: C1 Class: C2 Class: C3
    Sensitivity             0.9952    0.9715    0.9745    0.9865
    Specificity             0.9975    0.9948    0.9833    0.9982
    Pos Pred Value          0.9881    0.9859    0.9561    0.9955
    Neg Pred Value          0.9990    0.9894    0.9904    0.9948
    Prevalence              0.1752    0.2729    0.2721    0.2798
    Detection Rate          0.1744    0.2651    0.2651    0.2761
    Detection Prevalence    0.1765    0.2689    0.2773    0.2773
    Balanced Accuracy       0.9963    0.9832    0.9789    0.9924
```